# How to fill the screen cutout in the menu color kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How can I use kivy to paint the bangs on the smartphone screen in the color of the menu, as in the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDjQv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KivyMD doesn't have this feature yet